# How to use vue-hot-reload-api with vue-router without vue-loader?

Tags: vue.js

I use html-loader to write my vue component.
For example:
    import Vue from 'vue';

```
import template from './index.html';

export default {
    template,
    data() {
        return {

        };
    }
};
```

In the case, how to use vue-hot-reload-api with vue-router without vue-loader ?
I don't want to combine html, css and js into one file, I want to write them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate these files with this method:

```html
<!-- my-component.vue -->
<template src="./my-component.html"></template>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<style src="./my-component.css"></style>
```

**Source:** [VueJS: What About Separation of Concerns?](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns)